# Is it possible to change the label "model" for plot coefficients when using plot_summs in r?

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
library(jtools)

v1 <- rbinom(100, size=1, p=0.5)
v2 <- rnorm(1:100)
v3 <- rnorm(1:100)
v4<- rbinom(100, size=1, p=0.5)
mydf<- data.frame(v1, v2, v3, v4)


analysis1 <- glm(v1 ~ v2 + v3 + v4 )
analysis2 <- glm(v2 ~ v1 + v3 + v4 )


plot_summs(analysis1, analysis2, model.names = c("1", "2"))
```

And it produces a plot like this:
[image]

I want to change the label "Model" in the legend to "Type." I was wondering if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes (almost) everything is possible!

library(jtools) gives rather customized ggplot (S3) object back so default ggplot tricks like changing

```
p$label
```

won't work, however, luckily Jacob (the author) provides you with an optional argument:

```
plot_summs(analysis1, analysis2, model.names = c("1", "2"),legend.title = "Type")
```

which changes the legend title as expected.
[image]

---

*bonus hint :*

Please feel free to read more about the packages you are using on https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jtools/jtools.pdf
or by typing :

```
> ??jtools::plot_summs
```